# Is Palindrome subset of a regular language regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

Suppose we have $L$ being a regular language with alphabet $\Sigma$, if we define $M=\{ x \in \Sigma^{*}  \mid xx^{R} \in L  \}$, then we know that $M$ contains all half copies of palindrome strings of $L$, now here comes the question, is $M$ regular?

Is it easy to see that when $L$ is finite, then $M$ is clearly also finite hence regular. However, what if $L$ is infinite? I think it will be non-regular and try to pumping lemma but does not work...

Comment: First halves of palindromes and palindromes are very, very different.

Comment: With this sort of question, always try $\Sigma^*$ first.

Comment: He’s looking for first halves of palindromes, not complete palindromes, so that example is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subset of all palindromes in L is obviously not usually regular, take the simple example $a^*ba^*$ where the subset of palindromes $a^nba^n$ is not regular. But that is not the question. The question is about the set of all left halves of palindromes in L.

Assume you have an FSM for L (that is an FSM describing and defining L). You can take that FSM and use a simple algorithm to determine if w is in M:

Given a state S, define succ(S, a) as the state that the FSM will transition to from state S with input a, or nil if there is no transition for a. For a set of states T, define pred(T, a) as the set of states S such that succ(S, a) is not nil and an element of T.

To determine if w is in L, you would start with S = $S_0$. Then for every symbol s in w, you replace S with succ(S, s), exiting the loop if S is nil. Finally, w is in L if and only if S ≠ nil and S is an accepting state.

To determine if w is in M, you start with S = $S_0$ and T = set of accepting states. Then for every symbol s in w, you replace S with succ(S, s) and T with pred(T, s), exiting the loop if S is nil or T is empty. Finally, w is in M if and only if S ≠ nil and S is an element of T.

Instead of using this algorithm, you can quite easily construct an FSM for M.

Comment: Just bit confused how can we build an FSM for M based on the algorithm

Comment: Look at the algorithm. At every step there is a state which is a combination of S and T, and a clear description how to get from this state to the next. Create a new FSM with these states.