# Existence of a CFL $L$ such that $\sqrt{L}$ is not CFL

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma

Does there exist a CFL L such that the language defined as $L' = \sqrt{L} = \{w | ww \in L\}$ is not CFL? I feel that there is no such $L$ but obviously, I am unable to prove it.

I am sorry but I have not made any mentionable progress with my attempts on this problem.

I would appreciate any hint to the proof or a language $L$ that could satisfy this.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a question very similar in style (and solution): [Is Half - Palindrome subset of a context-free language context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116310/4287).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an example, and $L = \{a^nb^na^{2m}b^ka^k \mid n,m,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ does the trick. We get that $\sqrt{L} = \{a^nb^na^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which is a standard example of a non-context-free language.

To elaborate a bit on how to get there: CFLs can express that two numbers are the same, but not that three numbers are the same. So I want the square-root operation to introduce another equality, as it seems predisposed to do so.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. Is it possible to create an example parametrized with one variable, say $n$? I had been trying to solve this problem using such languages only which is why I couldn't find one probably.

Comment: @bigbang Close $\{ a^nb^n \mid n\in \mathbb N \} \cdot \{ a^na^n \mid n\in \mathbb N \} \cdot \{ b^na^n \mid n\in \mathbb N \}$.

Comment: @bigbang I can't give a definitive answer (we'd first need to formalize what "parameterized with one variable" would mean), but I think you were looking in the wrong place. I've added a bit of an explanation how I found the example.